# What species is this colourful caterpillar?

Tags: species-identification, zoology

What species is this colourful caterpillar found on a road in Central Europe?

[image: Caterpillar found on a road in Central Europe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by its appearance and location, that’s maybe a Pale Tussock (Calliteara pudibunda), a kind of moth found in Central Europe.

You can find some observations of that species on iNaturalist: https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/205294-Calliteara-pudibunda?locale=en-GB